# Lizmap add WFS layer with my own js (OpenLayers)

Tags: openlayers, qgis-server, lizmap

I'm looking for a way to add a WFS layer to my map powered by Lizmap Web Client (3.6) and QGIS server (3.28).

I can't succeed to call any method from OpenLayers api in my own JavaScript file.
I tried the wfs example from openlayers :

```
lizMap.events.on({
  uicreated: function(e) {
                
    var map = lizMap.map;
    const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      url: function (extent) {
        return (
          'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          'bbox=' +
          extent.join(',') +
          ',EPSG:3857'
        );
      },
      strategy: bboxStrategy,
    });

    const vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 2,
        }),
      }),
    });
    
    
    console.log(vector);
    map.addLayer(vector);
  }

});
```

Returns `VectorSource is not defined`

So I tried to import VectorSource at the begining of my file with `import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';`
returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Can someone confirm that all the Openlayers API is accessible from LWC ?
And confirm that the Openlayers API version is 8.2 (with LWC 3.6)?

If you have any clue to add a simple WFS layer and call any method from OpenLayers.

EDIT : Following @TomazicM comment, I've corrected `map.addLayer(vectorSource)` to `map.addLayer(vector)` but same result

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: As soon as I ve access to my laptop I will add some code that I have tested

Comment: It look OK, except that `map.addLayer(vectorSource)` should be `map.addLayer(vector)`.

Comment: Any other idea what can I try ?

Comment: No, since I'm not familiar with Lizmap.

Comment: I have posted a question in GitHub project. I'll report here if I have some info

Comment: Question in Github can be found here: https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/4091